# How can I check if the stack only get uniliteral letter?

Tags: c, stack

The program that I was trying to develop was reversing the input sentence by using the stack (first in last out). I just assumed that the input letter of the sentence would not exceed 100. To stop the program, the user only needs to input 'q' which is uniliteral letter. Below is the code that I designed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char stack[100];
int top = -1;

char push(char character) {
    if (top == 99) {
        return -1;
    }
    return stack[++top] = character;
}

char pop() {
    if (top == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return stack[top--];
}


int main(void) {

    while (1) {
        while (1) {
            char character;
            scanf_s("%c", &character);
            if (character == '\n') {
                break;
            }
            push(character);
        }



        if (stack[0] == 'q' && stack[1] == ' \n') {
            break;
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                printf("%c", pop());

            }
        }
        printf("\n"); 

    }

    
}
```

The program does what it has to; it reverses the sentence that I give as an input. However, it doesn't goes through 'break' when unliteral letter 'q' is given as an input.

Comment: That is _"a stack"_ not _"the stack"_.  _"the stack"_ will be assumed to refer to the program stack by most C programmers.

Comment: Where in your code are you testing any input character for a 'q'?

Comment: Hey don't perform a operations in a return statement, it might end badly

Answer (score 0):

Your termination test includes `... && stack[1] == ' \n'`, but you exit the input loop without stacking the `'\n'`.

Perhaps:

```
if( stack[0] == 'q' && top == 0 ) ...
```

i.e. test stack has `'q'` and only `'q'`. Or to put it another way; has exactly one item which is `'q'`.